# filter even and odd values from a dictionary and add these even and odd values to lists and write them to a txt file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, txt

code:

```
def even_odd_split(Dic1):
    even = []
    odd =  []
    for sublist in Dic1.values():
        for x in sublist:
            if x % 2 == 0:
            even.append(x)
            else:
            odd.append(x)
    return even, odd
 Dic1  = {"N1": [1, 3, 7, 6, 10],
      "N2": [2, 3, 9, 10, 21, 36],
      "N3": [4, 6, 5, 12, 24, 35],
      "N4": [0, 3, 14, 15, 16, 18]
     }

     print('Even items: %s\nOdd items%s' % even_odd_split(Dic1))

     with open("odd.txt","w") as f:
             f.write(str(odd))

     with open("even.txt","w") as f:
             f.write(str(even))
```

error: name 'odd' is not defined

Is it not found because it is empty in the lists but  I  add even and odd number. I do not understand why you gave such an error.How can i fix error?

Comment: You have code at the same indentation level as the method, but after the `return` statement. I think your indentation is broken, at least in this question

Comment: Indentation is also broken at the `if x % 2 == 0:` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables have a scope. If they are in a method, the variables are gone when the method is finished. That's why you `return` stuff.

At the place where you call the method, you can then assign the results of the method to new variables.

Since you return a tuple, you can have 2 variables at the assignment:

```
x, y = even_odd_split(Dic1)
```

Or, if you like to have the same names again

```
even, odd = even_odd_split(Dic1)
```

Here's the full code. Read it carefully and try to understand what it is all about with the names. Note that they are different inside and outside the method.

```
def even_odd_split(numbers):
    even_numbers = []
    odd_numbers = []
    for sublist in numbers.values():
        for x in sublist:
            if x % 2 == 0:
                even_numbers.append(x)
            else:
                odd_numbers.append(x)
    return even_numbers, odd_numbers


Dic1 = {"N1": [1, 3, 7, 6, 10],
        "N2": [2, 3, 9, 10, 21, 36],
        "N3": [4, 6, 5, 12, 24, 35],
        "N4": [0, 3, 14, 15, 16, 18]
        }

even, odd = even_odd_split(Dic1)
print(f'Even items: {even}\nOdd items: {odd}')

with open("odd.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(odd))

with open("even.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(even))
```